# Apache2.service: Failed with result 'signal'

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2

Why does my Apache server keep failing once in a while in my Ubuntu cloud server? For example, I will get this error when it fails:

```
apache2.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

The entire failed status:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Mon 2021-01-25 02:30:02 CET; 4h 6min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 180480 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 256217 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=killed, signal=TERM)
   Main PID: 180495 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 23 00:00:01 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 23 00:00:01 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 24 00:00:01 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 24 00:00:01 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 25 00:00:01 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 25 00:00:02 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 25 02:30:01 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 25 02:30:01 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Jan 25 02:30:02 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jan 25 02:30:02 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-1 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

My Apache log:

```
 [Mon Jan 25 00:00:02.525155 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 180495] AH01909: www.domnainxxx.co.uk:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 25 00:00:02.525900 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 180495] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 25 00:00:02.526149 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 180495] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 25 00:00:02.526159 2021] [core:notice] [pid 180495] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 25 00:20:39.087808 2021] [php7:error] [pid 255446] [client 3.8.12.221:15337] script '/var/www/lauthiamkok.net/nuxt-static/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 25 00:20:39.126883 2021] [php7:error] [pid 255447] [client 3.8.12.221:16451] script '/var/www/lauthiamkok.net/nuxt-static/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 25 02:30:02.398089 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 180495] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 25 06:37:14.744299 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 257635] AH01909: www.domnainxxx.co.uk:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 25 06:37:14.744965 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 257635] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 25 06:37:14.803233 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 257637] AH01909: www.domnainxxx.co.uk:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 25 06:37:14.803601 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 257637] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 25 06:37:14.808029 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 257637] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 25 06:37:14.808058 2021] [core:notice] [pid 257637] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

It seems that the failure is caused by SSL?

`server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name` - what does it mean?

Comment: Two questions: (1) is this running on a Raspberry Pi? (2) is there anything else in the Apache log that might point to a pattern for when errors occur? (For example, is it *always* at 2:30am?)

Comment: @Matigo 1) no. it's running on a cloud server at https://www.hetzner.com/, 
1 vCPU
2 GB RAM
20 GB Disk space
20 TB Traffic

2) I updated my questions for the Apache log.